# Html - How to align a <p> tag within a <p> tag to the center without breaking into next line?

Tags: html, css

I have a `<p>` tag within a `<p>` tag. I am using the second `<p>` tag to do formatting of texts in between the line. I want to print those in the same line and align it to the center of the page. I tried few css tricks like `text-align:center;` `display:inline-block;` even the simple `align:center` but since I have other `<p>` tags within, it breaks into next line.

Can anyone suggest me a feasible way to do this?

```html
<p style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; position: relative">
  Followers:
  <p style="font-size:20px; display:inline-block; text-align:center;">100</p>
  Following:
  <p style="font-size:20px; display:inline-block; text-align:center;">200</p>
  Tweets:
  <p style="font-size:20px; display:inline-block; text-align:center;">2113</p>
</p>
```

Comment: You **can't** nest `<p>` elements. The HTML parsing rules mean that a `</p>` is inserted before the `<p>` implicitly. Try writing meaningful HTML before worry about styling it.

Comment: Also please when you post HTML or CSS questions, post HTML instead of server code in a `[<>]` snippet. This is NOT a jinja2 issue at all. I updated your question to a [mcve]

Answer (score -4):

Replace the `<p>` inside `<p>` should be solve it

```html
<p style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; position: relative">
  Followers:
  <body style="font-size:20px; display:inline-block; text-align:center;">100</body> <br />
  Following:
  <body style="font-size:20px; display:inline-block; text-align:center;">200</body> <br />
  Tweets:
  <body style="font-size:20px; display:inline-block; text-align:center;">2113</body> <br />
</p>
```

Comment: body? Your HTML should only have one set of body tags - perhaps you mean span or div?

Comment: Hmm that's should be better. I still learning